# How to achieve left alignment on uilabel (same as suggestions appear in native keyboard)?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

What I am trying to achieve (and I am not 100% sure how to do it or how to explain it properly) is described in the below screenshot.

I have added `allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation = true` and `lineBreakMode = .byClipping` to my label, but it now displays the beginning of the word and I need to display the end of the word, any ideas on how to achieve that? or any ideas what to look for in apple docs? I've read everything I could think of so far.

[image]

Comment: Can't get your question properly but what you want to achieve is doable with lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead.

Comment: Trying to clarify your question... You have a fixed-width `UILabel`? and, if the text is too long to fit, you want to see the **end** of the text? Have you tried setting the text alignment to **Right** instead of **Left**, with **Truncate Head**?

Comment: @ChanpreetSingh if you would've open the photo I attached, you would've noticed that I am not looking for adding "..." at the beginning of the word. if you don't bother opening the image attached and you say you don't get my question, please don't answer. this is not what I asked, line break mode set to .byClipping gives me exactly what I need for the word, except for the shift to the end of the word :) there is an image with a circle drawn on top of the word I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: @DonMag thanks for the suggestion, it doesn't work unfortunately, I have some custom views and yes, the width is fixed, I was looking to achieve what I attached in the image (if possible by any means) without modifying the width (what I think I can clarify is that I want the mode of .byTruncatingHead without actually truncating/adding the "...")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get that result, you need to embed the label in a `UIView` and constrain the label's Trailing but not Leading.

Make sure the "holder" view has Clips To Bounds set to true.

As the label grows in width, it will extend past the leading edge of the holder view.

Here's a quick example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let theLabel = UILabel()
    let holderView = UIView()
    
    let strs: [String] = [
        "Misinterpret",
        "Misinterpreted",
        "Misinterpretation",
    ]
    var idx = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        holderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        holderView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        theLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        theLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 30.0)
        
        holderView.addSubview(theLabel)
        view.addSubview(holderView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            holderView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            holderView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            holderView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            holderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theLabel.heightAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            
            theLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.centerYAnchor),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
        ])
        
        // clip theLabel when it gets too wide
        holderView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        theLabel.text = strs[idx]
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        idx += 1
        theLabel.text = strs[idx % strs.count]
    }
    
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The "type ahead" suggestion bar probably also uses a gradient mask so the text does not look so abruptly clipped... but that's another question.

---

**Edit** - here's a more complete example.

- textField at the top
- label in a gray "holder" view
- green label showing actual size of text

As you enter text, the labels will update.

The label in the gray box will be centered horizontally, until it is too wide to fit, at which point it will stay "right-aligned." It will also have a slight gradient mask at the left edge so it is not cut off abruptly.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let textField = UITextField()
    
    let theClippedLabel = UILabel()
    let holderView = UIView()

    // plain label showing the actual size
    let theActualLabel = UILabel()

    let leftEdgeFadeMask = CAGradientLayer()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [textField, theClippedLabel, holderView, theActualLabel].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        holderView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        theClippedLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        theActualLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        
        textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        textField.placeholder = "Type here..."
        textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didEdit(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
        
        theClippedLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 30.0)
        theActualLabel.font = theClippedLabel.font
        
        holderView.addSubview(theClippedLabel)
        view.addSubview(holderView)
        view.addSubview(theActualLabel)
        view.addSubview(textField)
        
        // center label horizontally, unless it is wider than holderView (minus Left/Right "padding")
        let cx = theClippedLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.centerXAnchor)
        cx.priority = .defaultHigh
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // center a 200-pt wide "holder" view
            holderView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            holderView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            holderView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0),
            
            // holderView height is 16-pts taller than the label height (8-pts Top / Bottom "padding")
            holderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theClippedLabel.heightAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            
            // center the label vertically
            theClippedLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.centerYAnchor),
            
            // keep the label's Trailing edge at least 8-pts from the holderView's Trailing edge
            theClippedLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: holderView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            // activate cx constraint
            cx,
            
            theActualLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            theActualLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.centerXAnchor),
            
            textField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -12.0),
            
        ])
        
        // clip theLabel when it gets too wide
        holderView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        // gradient mask for left-edge of label
        leftEdgeFadeMask.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
        leftEdgeFadeMask.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        leftEdgeFadeMask.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        leftEdgeFadeMask.locations = [0.0, 0.1]
        theClippedLabel.layer.mask = leftEdgeFadeMask
        
        // so we have something to see when we start
        theClippedLabel.text = " "
        theActualLabel.text = theClippedLabel.text
    }

    @objc func didEdit(_ sender: Any) {

        // if the textField is empty, use a space character so
        //  the labels don't disappear
        var str = " "
        if let s = textField.text, !s.isEmpty {
            str = s
        }
        theClippedLabel.text = str
        theActualLabel.text = str
        updateMask()

    }
    
    func updateMask() -> Void {
        
        // update label frame
        theClippedLabel.sizeToFit()
        
        // we want the gradient mask to start at the leading edge
        //  of the holder view, with
        //  4-pts Left and 8-pts Right "padding"
        var r = holderView.bounds
        
        let targetW = r.width - 12
        r.size.width -= 12
        r.size.height -= 16
        r.origin.x = theClippedLabel.bounds.width - targetW
        
        // disable built-in layer animations
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
        
        leftEdgeFadeMask.frame = r
        
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
    
}
```

Example result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that this is **example code only**. In practical use, we'd want to build this as a custom view with all of the sizing and gradient mask logic self-contained.

Comment: thank you very much for the example, I did indeed have a custom view already, still trying to figure this out, but I marked your example as the correct answer in case someone else in the future tries to figure this out and needs an example for implementing the behaviour :)